# YouTube API is it possible to return all of the comments ever made by a user?

Tags: api, youtube

I have VERY limited use of the YouTube API.

I am messing about in the sandbox.

But I would really like to know if it's possible to return all of the comments, made by a certain username?

I'd love to be able to track my own comments on YT videos that I have made?

To be able to see which comment was made against which video?

That would be amazing.

I have made a cursory look into the API and the browser options - but there isn't any way to do as far as I know?

I mess around with the API would I be able to find a call that returns what I am looking for?

Any help? I can't be the 1st person to want this?

Comment: Off-topic, but you _can_ do it in the browser now, in the History tab, by selecting "Comments".